# Diseño de estructura de una base de datos para estadísticas de baloncesto

Tags: base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos, tablas

me he decidido a pedir ayuda aquí porque tengo algunas dudas en la creación de mi primera base de datos.

Me gustaría almacenar estadísticas de baloncesto, actuales e históricas, en una base de datos. Al principio pensé que sería fácil de estructurar pero según empiezo me van surgiendo más posibilidades y ya no sé muy bien cual sería la mejor forma de organizar las tablas.

Parto de las estadísticas de cada jugador en cada partido (minutos, puntos, faltas, rebotes etc...) y a partir de ahí se genera todas las estadísticas de los equipos, de los partidos, de la temporada y demás.

Mi duda es si es mejor crear una tabla para cada jugador donde cada celda sea un partido que recoja, además de las estadísticas personales, la temporada, el equipo, el rival, la fecha, el campo... Cada tabla tendría muchas celdas y muchas columnas ya que hay jugadores veteranos que han jugado muchos partidos, nacionales e internacionales. Obviamente esto me daría como resultado muchas tablas (miles quizás) y no sé si es la mejor manera de proceder y si luego será un lío acceder a todo eso.

Luego me surgen otras dudas sobre si debo crear tablas independientes para los equipos, entrenadores etc pero me gustaría saber vuestra opinión sobre cual sería la mejor estructura antes de meterme en otras cuestiones.

Muchas gracias, como siempre y un saludo

Comment: Si estas pensando que necesitas muchas tablas, antes de siquiera tratar de empezar con algo asi deberias revisar mucha teoria de base de datos. Sobre todo que se guarda en las tablas y que se guarda en las filas.

Comment: Te recomiendo buscar información sobre como crear modelos entidad-relación ya que es de ayuda a la hora de diseñar una base de datos. Ten en cuenta que la idea es crear las tablas justas y necesarias con sus columnas correspondientes, si luego cada tabla tiene cientos o miles de registros no es un problema.

Answer (score 0):

**Una tabla por jugador** definitivamente **no sería una buena opción**.

Revisa esta estructura, es probable que te sirva de ejemplo para tu proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]